# Define memory usage or field size using macro with reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, macros, struct

Recently I saw this macro:

```
#define asOFFSET(s,m) ((size_t)(&reinterpret_cast<s*>(100000)->m)-100000)
```

I have found this as the approach to calculate the position offset of any item `m` of any `struct s` from the beginning of the structure.

However when I ran it and compared the calculation for two structures `MyStuct2` and `MyStruct3`, which differ only by one `int var3` added to `MyStruct3` at the beginning, I got the difference 8 bytes, not 4 as I expected.

This is the code I run:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define asOFFSET(s,m) ((size_t)(&reinterpret_cast<s*>(100000)->m)-100000)


struct MyStruct1 {int var1; int a;};
struct MyStruct2 {long var2; int a;};
struct MyStruct3 {int var3; long var4; int a;};

int main (void)
{

 printf("%d\n",(int)asOFFSET(MyStruct1,a));
 printf("%d\n",(int)asOFFSET(MyStruct2,a));
 printf("%d\n",(int)asOFFSET(MyStruct3,a));

 // Result:
 // 4
 // 8
 // 16

}
```

and this is the output it gives:

```
4
8
16
```

My question is how can I fix the real memory in order to have one `int` taking 4 bytes and not 8?
Thanks.

Comment: alignment.. platform specific and definitely not portable (you should specify your compiler + platform for a better answer)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment